# Modal dialog appearing only after one round of clicking the actionButton

Tags: r, shiny

I want this app to show a modal dialog with the title "All locations" when the actionButton is clicked and the ID of map location whenever the map marker is clicked. However, the dialog associated to the map markers will only display after one round of clicking the actionButton. I also don't want the modal dialog to show up at start (this happened to me exploring other options). What am I missing?

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
data <- PlantGrowth
data$Lat <- runif(nrow(data), 40, 41)
data$Lon <- runif(nrow(data), -1, 3)
data <- rbind(data[1,], data[11,])

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  leafletOutput("map", height="100vh"),
  absolutePanel(style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px",
                top = 10, left = 10, width = 300, height = "auto",
                actionButton("button", "Show all data")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  Title <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    Title("All locations")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$map_marker_click, {
    Title(input$map_marker_click$id)
          }) 
  
    observeEvent({input$map_marker_click 
                  input$button}, {
      showModal(
        modalDialog(
          title = Title() 
        )
      )
    })
  
  output$map<-
    renderLeaflet({
      plot.map <-
        leaflet(
          data = data, options = leafletOptions(zoomControl = F)
        ) %>% 
        addTiles() %>% 
        addCircleMarkers(
          lat = ~ Lat, lng = ~ Lon,
          weight = 1,
          layerId = ~ group,
          fillOpacity = 0.8,
          color = "black",
          opacity = 0.7,
          options = markerOptions(riseOnHover = TRUE))
      return(plot.map)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "one round"? (pardon my English)

Comment: I mean that I have to click the actionButton at least one time before I can get a reaction (i.e. modal dialog appearing with location title) by clicking any of the map markers. After clicking the actionButton once, the App works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works:

```r
  observeEvent(list(input$map_marker_click, input$button), {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        title = Title() 
      )
    )
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
```